# Print closing tags with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, tags, beautifulsoup

This code prints out all tags:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)
    for child in soup.recursiveChildGenerator():
    name = getattr(child, "name", None)
    if name is not None:
       print name
```

Is it possible to print out closing tags too?

Example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>My First Heading</h1>
        <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Prints:

```
html
body
h1
p
```

I want it to print:

```
html
body
h1
/h1
p
/p
/body
/html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with that mechanism. You'll need to recurse manually, outputting the close tag after the recursion attempt.